# Tcl backslash substitution is not working the way I'd imagined

Tags: tcl, expect

I have not been able to find a way to submit a pattern (created by autoexpect) as a pattern to the expect command via a variable.

An early version of one of my test scripts used a hand-edited version of an autoexpect script to automate testing of an application and it worked pretty well.  Unfortunately it was not exactly maintainable, and following changes in the app I thought I'd break the test into a series of interactions, with the autoexpect patterns being stored in a series of ascii files, and then run a procedure to match each fragment in turn.  A typical fragment looks like this (when displayed in vi):

```
run_db\r
\r
\r
\r
```

Just for completeness, here is the same fragment displayed by hexdump:

```
0000000   r   u   n   _   d   b   \   r  \n   \   r  \n   \   r  \n   \
0000010   r  \n
```

So, my fragment includes control character "\n" and escaped sequences "\""r" (if you see what I mean!)

My procedure reads this string from my ascii file into a variable (I used "read -nonewline" to do so.)

I then tried to run expect against the pattern with:

```
expect {
   -gl "$pattern_string" { commands... 
   }
timeout { commands...
   }
}
```

But, the pattern is never matched!  Even weirder, if I substitute the string itself directly into the expect command (rather than via the variable) expect matches perfectly, so long as I insert a "\n" after each "\r":

```
expect {
   -gl "run_db\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n" { commands... 
   }
timeout { commands...
   }
}
```

(I'm not at all clear to me why the "\n" sequences are necessary.  They aren't in the hexdump, so I'd have imagined this *shouldn't* have matched!)

I've probably misunderstood substitution.  It is as though I need to replace the "\" "r" pairs with 0x0a, and then substitute the variable into the expect command.  (It may be that there are other escaped characters lurking elsewhere in my autoexpect file.  It is pretty big.)  Anyway, I've tried to match the following new variable with no success:

```
set substituted_pattern [ subst $pattern_string ]
```

Any and all suggestions very gratefully received... Allan.

Comment: How do you declare `$pattern_string`? Show how 
you `set` that variable.

Comment: HI glenn, thanks for your interest...  I don't declare it as such (I wasn't aware that you could declare variables in Tcl?), but it is initialised with: set pattern_string [ read -nonewline $pattern_channel_id ]

Comment: And that file contains the characters "backslash" + "r" and not a literal carriage return?

Comment: The whole problem lies in that `autoexpect` replaces a real received carriage-return by the 2 characters `\r` (but keeps the real newline). When you read the pattern file you need to convert these 2 chars back to a real carriage-return, which expect does if you use a literal string `"\r"` but not when it is inside a variable.

Comment: For me it's never a good idea to generate Expect scripts for serious use with autoexpect. For most cases it's much easier to write the script on your own.

Comment: Hi Glenn, thanks for your interest... Yes indeed, the autoexpect file includes the two plaintext characters "\" and "r" rather than the literal 0x0a.

Comment: Hi Meuh, I think you've identified the issue.  I need to investigate how to perform that substitution, though the subst command didn't seem to do it when first I tried it.  I'll return to that approach and let you all know!

Comment: Hi Emily E, my problem is that this is a character-interface application which has loads of screen manipulation.  I cannot imagine (other than to use autoexpect) how to accurately capture the application screen output.  I did wonder whether there is a way to read back the contents of an xterm window but apparently there isn't!  I'd be interested to know how you efficiently code your patterns; can you point me to a reference?  Best wishes.

Comment: I remember writing unit tests of a bios "TUI" over a serial console, and it was fairly awful to do. I dont remember finding any helpful utilities. The implementation was in Python which has `pexpect()` that is like `expect`. It also has/had a deprecated `ANSI.ANSI()` routine that interpreted vt100-like escapes so you can get a readable version of what should be on the screen at any point, which helped a bit. (Note: to send a reply to someone who comments on your Post, you need to add an `@` and their name (use tab to autofill after 3 characters)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too clear on tcl's parsing of backslash in various situations, but empirically what should work would be to replace the two characters `\r` by a real carriage-return, because this is what you will get from the `expect` read. You can do this with:

```
regsub -all {\\r} $pattern_string "\r" pat2
```

which sets variable `pat2` to the new version.

Comment: I have an update. I got confused with what you were going to be getting from expect, as opposed to the file.

Comment: Thank you meuh!  I was sure that I'd tried this when you posted it, but could not get you solution to work.  I've just retried and the problem is solved!  I'm sort-of assuming that when an update is applied to a comment there is nothing to indicate the change in the comment itself then?  In any case, I'm very grateful and I've learned a lot.  Thanks again.

Comment: No, you are right. The answer i posted before was wrong and I edited it a day later when I added the comment above. (To see the edit it might depend on how many points you have?).

Answer (score 0):

The character sequence `\r` is interpreted by the glob matcher as matching a single literal `r` (the backslash isn't very useful here, but is more useful when used with a glob metacharacter like `*`, `?` or `[`). You should either double up the backslashes in the string (i.e., `\\r`) or use exact matching (`-ex`). For example:

```
expect {
   -ex "$pattern_string" {
      commands... 
   }
   timeout {
      commands...
   }
}
```

It's also possible to process the string to make it work with glob matching using `string map`:

```
set processed_pattern [string map {{\r} {\\r}} $pattern_string]
expect {
   -gl "$processed_pattern" {
      commands... 
   }
   timeout {
      commands...
   }
}
```

Comment: Tcl is certainly a huge language.  Does anyone know all of it?  Thanks for the suggestion Donal, will try the "string map" match next.  This probably deserves a new thread but is there any reason why I shouldn't store the match type in a variable then run something like [ expect -$match_type $pattern_string ... ] ?  I could parameterise my expect proc and make it more flexible...

Comment: Ok Donal, I'm afraid neither of your suggestions worked.  However, I've written a diagnostic string dump and here are the first 15 characters of pattern_string after using your "string map" suggestion: `code`   0:  0x72      r
  1:  0x75      u
  2:  0x6e      n
  3:  0x5f      _
  4:  0x64      d
  5:  0x62      b
  6:  0x5c      \
  7:  0x5c      \
  8:  0x72      r
  9:  0x0a   <LF>
 10:  0x5c      \
 11:  0x5c      \
 12:  0x72      r
 13:  0x0a   <LF>
 14:  0x5c      \
 15:  0x5c      \
`code`  As you can see, the pattern string is a mix of ascii and text characters...

Comment: Apologies for the appalling layout of my pattern string dump above... cannot work out how to put code into a comment and the online help didn't.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I've included the code supplied by meuh above and that worked.  I've wasted hours, but coming here has saved me days... :-)